# Regular expressions Url rewriting - How to put a dash instead of the slash on url without parameters errors

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following regular expressions on `mu .htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?content=product&productid=$1&productitle=$2&categoryname=$3
```

On the browser I get this: 
http://localhost/mysite/4/rome-walking-shared/rome

I'd like to have the like this:
http://localhost/mysite/4-rome-walking-shared/rome
where the product id is joined to the produc title by a `"-"` not a `"/"`

If I try to put the `"-"` instead the `"/"` like

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$
```

I get a Php error as the $get parameter of the product id is not recognized

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What is the PHP error and can you share the PHP code?

Comment: Yes sure The php error is:
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/class/product.class.php on line 385

Comment: Okay, you need to update the variable pull out the integer. You also should use error reporting on the query because it failed and your code silently continued to assume it worked.

Comment: Thanks so much friend, it works :-) I will post a reply very soon to mark this issue solved, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too much thinking at the regular expression that I forgot to check the value of the variable which takes the $Get value from the URL. So by the 2nd regular expression : RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$

the url takes this value :  http://localhost/mysite/4-rome-walking-shared/rome

and the $get variable used for the query to the Db takes the string value of "4-rome-walking-shared", using intval the value become 4 and it is possible to make the db query without errors.